# Prevent string from breaking to new line in MessageBox

Tags: c#, winforms, formatting, messagebox

Is there a way to prevent the MessageBox from breaking a string instead of just growing to the width of the string?  I'm porting an old VB application and they use message boxes to present a sizable amount of data to the user.  I suppose I could create a form, but I've already started down this road, and would not like to have to go back.

Thanks.

Comment: [A little about the MessageBox](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/06/24/10178386.aspx)

Comment: Joel, thanks for the link.  This was exactly what I was afraid of.  Well at least I can rip the bandaid off and it will only hurt for just a second and I can get on with porting the application.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The only (supported) way to have such control over how things get laid out here is to ditch the MessageBox helper class and build a custom Form class that does what you need.

Comment: Robert, thanks for the answer.  Joel posted a link above that goes into the details.

Answer (score 1):

We have dealt with this issue in the past be embedding newlines (\r\n) in the text of our message.  MessageBox will grow vertically to honor the wrapping text.  We used to have MessageBoxs so wide you couldn't even see the centered buttons, but now they show up fine.

Depending on the complexity of generating the message text and/or whether you have control over that, this may be your simplest solution.  Otherwise, I think you will need to create your own form.

For example:

```
MessageBox.Show("Line1\r\nLine2\r\nLine3\r\nLine4", "MessageBox test");
MessageBox.Show("Line1 Line2 Line3 Line4", "MessageBox test");
```

The first line creates a MessageBox with 4 lines of text and the window has grown to the correct height to show all.  The second line creates a MessageBox with a single line and the appropriate width to show the whole line.

Comment: What is weird for me is that I am using the tab character successfully, however for some reason, I have a space between two words on a line, and the message box chooses to break there.  I don't understand why it would choose to break in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: I have never seen that behavior.  I wasn't sure from the question title if you wanted to keep the full message and get a very wide messagebox window or find a way to get a more readable messagebox window.  My answer would get you a more readable messagebox.

Comment: check Joel's link above.  It's regretably all there.

Comment: We still run on XP at work, so I hadn't seen this.  The Win7 migration is picking up steam, so at least I'll be prepared for this issue.

Comment: Yeah, it was simple enough to just create a form and have it look and behave like a MessageBox.  I put a single rich text edit control in a dockable panel and docked the edit control to fit the size of the panel.  Haven't put icon's in yet, but I'm sure that won't be an issue.